# drawListRow only call on focused rows (Blackberry 4.5)

Tags: blackberry, listfield

It always draw all focus elements , but it doesnt refresh the others until listfield is scrolled. That's only a problem in Blackberry 4.5 , 5.0 is ok.

I have tried to do the next before draw anything intoe the row :

```
    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics,int index, int y, int width) 
    {
        listField.invalidate(); //My try
             ...
    }
```

But it doesn't run .

**Update**

Ok , no invalidate().

I'll show you my problem better with an Image:

[image]

Thanks for reading . Any idea?

Comment: dont put an invalidate inside drawlistrow();

Answer (score 1):

What your code snippet will do is every time one row is drawn, invalidate the entire field causing all visible rows to be redrawn, which will invalidate the entire field...

I hope some one at RIM thought of that and aborts the invalidate call. I can't give you any more ideas without more specific information about what you are doing with your user interface.

Comment: you took words out of my mouth, the code above is as if there is an invalidate() inside paint();

Comment: @Richard i have updated with an image with my problem . Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the symptoms are, but that doesn't help diagnose what may be wrong with your code.